# How to record audio m4a format audio file in android?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediarecorder, m4a

I am able to record audio file as .m4 format using media recorder,but it is not support in all media player.so i want to record audio file in m4a like iOS in android.

```
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile("test.mp4");
```

So, Is there any way i can record audio file in m4a format in android?

Please reply if anyone have solution for this issue.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

i think you have to set the

```
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

i've a problem with playing the recorded sound on Windows. On my Android Smartphone i can load the recorded file und play them.

Could you jagdish play the recorded sound on Windows?

Comment: I have not tried in windows but able to play in linux.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, my application writes some files and I try a web portal where it is possible to listen to these audios, for this to work I changed the enconder to AudioEncoder.**AAC** and it worked well for me, but the file size is much larger, if you have no problem with the file size, maybe it will work for you, too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)